# What is the best way to move the powershell console window to the left side of the screen?

Tags: powershell

Trying to move the current, active powershell window to the left side of the screen using a PowerShell script.

I've found [this function](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Set-the-position-and-size-54853527), but it doesn't really come with any examples.

Comment: There are examples, e.g. `Get-Process powershell | Set-Window -X 2040 -Y 142 -Passthru`

Comment: Thanks. After I got some sleep and returned to this, I read the code and found the details in the script. I should really get more sleep. :)

Comment: The link to the code is dead.

Comment: That link is from 2017! Microsoft obviously moved the page some where else.

Here's another example that can help: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SciProfile/0.3.0/Content/PSModuleUtils%5CFunctions%5CSet-Window.ps1

Answer (score 6):

Funny and interesting question.

If you want move window, you need to know the Window handle `hWnd` of it. For console you can do it by using the `GetConsoleWindow` function from **kernel32.dll**.

This script, it will move powershell console to *upper-left* with size `(500, 500)`.

```
Add-Type -Name Window -Namespace Console -MemberDefinition '
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")] 
public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int W, int H); '

$consoleHWND = [Console.Window]::GetConsoleWindow();
$consoleHWND
[Console.Window]::MoveWindow($consoleHWND,0,0,500,500);
```

If you know the **hWnd** of the window you can do many things with that window. You can find all functions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468919(v=vs.85).aspx).

But this script work will only work with a real powershell *console*. If you will start it from `Powershell ISE`, **hWnd** will be Zero `0`, because Powershell ISE don't have real console in it.

Answer (score 2):

To give you a complete example with `Set-Window` which mimics the manual <kbd>Window</kbd>+<kbd>Left-Arrow</kbd>.

On my 1920*1200 screen the window dimensions after <kbd>Window</kbd>+<kbd>Left-Arrow</kbd> are:

```
#  Left    Top  Width Heigth
#    -7      0    974   1207
```

So you need to get the screen dimensions first, for the primary monitor this will do:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$ScreenSize = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize

$MyLeft  = -7
$MyTop   = 0
$MyWidth = $ScreenSize.Width/2+2*7
$MyHeight= $ScreenSize.Height +7

"Left:{0}  Top:{1}  Width:{2}  Height:{3}" -f $MyLeft,$MyTop,$MyWidth,$MyHeight
Get-Process powershell | Set-Window -X $MyLeft -Y $MyTop -Width $MyWidth -Height $MyHeight
```

Comment: `Set-Window` doesn't exists in powershell. Please provide a working link to that cmdlet.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way for moving window of the current posh process:

```
$MethodDefinition = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);
'@
$User32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinition -Name 'User32' -Namespace 'Win32' -PassThru

$CurrentProcess = Get-Process -id $PID
$User32::SetWindowPos($CurrentProcess.MainWindowHandle, 0x1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0040 -bor 0x0020 -bor 0x0001)
```

Comment: Can you please describe what your code does (or how it works)?

Comment: No problem. power-shell script can use any windows dynamic load library (DLL). In code, we just do import of the user32 system library and use function from that library.

Comment: I was thinking about the `0x0040 -bor 0x0020 -bor 0x0001` part.

Comment: Yep, it's a bitwize boolean manipulation within flags. The more details could be found in the API definitions for a [SetWindowPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) function. I.e. it looks like ```SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOSIZE```